# Cross Validation JAVA WEKA

Tags: weka

I need to run classifiers on WEKA however using the command line and perform 10 folds cross-validation. What would be the command lines for performing cross-validation? The algorithms I need to run are MLP, SMO, and Random Forest. I got the commands for these algorithms, but I need to perform cross-validation.

Answer (score 0):

To perform cross validation using the WEKA CLI, all you need is to omit the `Test File` command (i.e. the `T` parameter). This will result into performing CV on the training data.

Using the `x` parameter to set the number of folds.

Check out this website for full details about WEKA CLI commands : [https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~remco/weka_bn/node13.html](https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/%7Eremco/weka_bn/node13.html)